# validate the check box or radio box

Tags: javascript

```
function arrayToHtmlTable($arr,$page,$category_name) {
    if ($arr > 0) {
        foreach ($arr[0] as $t=>$v)
            $colnams[] = $t;
    }

    $r = '';
    $r.='<form action="del.php" method="POST" name="check" onsubmit ="check();" >';
    $r.='<input type=submit name="delete" value="delete"  style="margin-left: 1195px;">';

    if($page=="coupon") {
        $r.='<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Toggle All<br/>';
    }

    $r.='<input type=submit name="update" value="update" style="margin-left: 1195px;">';
    $r.='<input type="hidden" name="page" value="'.$page.'">';

    if($page=="coupon") {
        $r.='<input type="hidden" name="category_name" value="'.$category_name.'">';
    }

    $r .=' <table cellpadding="10" border="1" style="width:550px;"><tr>';

    for($i=0; $i<count($colnams); $i++)  {
        $r .= "<td>$colnams[$i]</td>";
    }     

    $r .= '<td>DELETE/Update</td>';
    $r .= '</tr>';

    for ($i=0; $i<count($arr) ; $i++) {
        $r .='<tr>';

        for ($ii=0; $ii < count($colnams); $ii++) {
            $e= serialize($arr[$i][$colnams[$ii]]);
            $j=unserialize($e);
            $r .= "<td>$j</td>";
        }

        if ($page=="coupon") {
            $r .= '<td><input type="checkbox" name="del[]" value="'.$arr[$i]['id'].'"></td>';
        }

        if ($page=="category") {
            $r .= '<td><input type="radio" name="del[]" id="del" value="'.$arr[$i]['id'].'"></td>';
        }

        $r .="</tr>";
    }     

    $r .=   '</table>';

    return $r;
}
```

This is my function which convert the array into the table form which is **$arr**, I am working on two pages (i.e., category or coupon) which is **$page**. I am weak in JavaScript. I have tried to validate checkbox or radio box for respective pages but to don't know where to put the `onsubmit.`

Comment: Just post the generated html and explain a little more what the javascript has to do...

Comment: The code you've posted only shows you generating HTML. It has nothing to do with validating any form elements.

Comment: Use this function and there are two button ie delete and update when the user click on it without clicking on the radio box or check box , it will redirect to the next page . i want to stop it

Comment: @crush i knw this function just convert it to table , but there are checkbox , so i want whenever user click on the delete or update button    without clicking on the check box , it will not redirect on the next page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may help.

```
if ($('.yourCheckbox').is(':checked')) {
  //its checked, run code
}else {
    return false;
}
```